# Change velocity log file location in upstream project

Tags: java, logging, velocity

I have a Java web application that uses a library that initializes/configures Velocity.

We're migrating this project from WebLogic to Tomcat.

The application now throws errors, traced to Velocity. When Velocity is initialized, the default location for the log file is in a directory which the application doesn't have permissions to write to, thus Velocity is never initialized.

I tried to create a `velocity.properties` file in the upstream project in my `WEB-INF/classes` directory (mirroring the folder structure of the Velocity jar file itself), but this doesn't seem to have changed anything. Velocity is still failing to initialize.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish what I'm describing? I don't want to touch the library which is initializing Velocity–I'd rather just override the log file location in the upstream project.

Comment: Overriding a file on the classpath relies on classpath resolution, which you'll tend to have little control over. If the library uses a hard-coded location, and you can't change it using normal log configuration, I'm not sure you'll be able to change it reliably, if the library doesn't have a mechanism for defining things externally.

Answer (score 1):

In your WEB-INF directory look at web.xml and look for `<param-name>configURI</param-name>` and it's `<param-value>` that follows.

For example my web.xml has this

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>configURI</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/scripts</param-value>
</init-param>
```

In my WEB-INF/scripts is where my velocity.properties file is

This is the property in velocity.properties that controls the log file location

```
runtime.log =
```

Which specifies the full path to my velocity.log

Mine looks like this

```
runtime.log =/var/log/velocity.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tad, however I am not using / configuring Java servlets.

Comment: @ZacharyCarter I was just using my setup as an example to show where my velocity.properties file was `WEB-INF/scripts` vs `WEB-INF/classes`. Once you find the directory that your setup is reading configuration/properties files from you can put the velocity.properties file in there and hopefully have better luck getting it to initialize.